# phpMailer not sending attachmnets

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I have the following phpmailer function that works except that it's not attaching the attachment. The function does echo "found attachment".  Are there other settings that have to be tweaked to allow attachments?

```
function mailerExpressBlueHostSWAG(array $mailInputs){   

    require_once '../include/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsMail();   
    $mail->SetFrom('swag@sustainablewestonma.org');
    $mail->addAddress($mailInputs['addAddress']);   // use for production; 


    if(file_exists("../uploads/" . $mailInputs['name']))echo 'found attachment';   
    $mail->addAttachment("../uploads/" . $mailInputs['name']);

    $mail->addEmbeddedImage("../../../uploads/2019/09/newswagimageSmall.jpg", "swag-logo");

    $body = $mailInputs['body'] ;   
    $mail->Subject = $mailInputs['subject'] ;
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->ContentType="text/HTML";   

    if(1==1){
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'mail not sent <br>' ;
            return 'Message could not be sent.' . 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }else{
            echo 'mail sent 2<br>';
            return 'Message has been sent';
       }
   }
   $mail->ClearAddresses();   
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$mailInputs['name']`? Enable error reporting also just to make sure there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, you're using an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

This code is somewhat confused:

```
if(file_exists("../uploads/" . $mailInputs['name']))echo 'found attachment';   
$mail->addAttachment("../uploads/" . $mailInputs['name']);
```

That condition will not apply to the `addAttachment` call because you've got no `{}` around it.

The main problem is that checking that a file exists doesn't mean you can read it. `addAttachment` returns true if it can read the file, so use that to check directly:

```
if (!$mail->addAttachment("../uploads/" . $mailInputs['name'])) {
    echo 'File could not be read';
}
```

If that complains, check ownership and permission son the file.